# Necessary punctuation in sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas, dashes

There was a sentence in a released* ACT test a while back. This was the sentence.

"I ride this trail nearly everyday - not on a bike, but on 'Luigi'."

It seems to me that the interior punctuation is not necessary and might be for emphasis. I suppose this is somehow related to the similar "not only...but also" clause. I was looking over this page about this phrasing, and the first example seems to get rid of interior punctuation too:

https://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-not-this-but-that-parallelism-problems/

*Just want to clarify that I mean *public* if there are any concerns.

Comment: I'm all for getting rid of as much extraneous punctuation as possible but the bare *I ride this trail nearly everyday not on a bike but on 'Luigi'*  calls out for something before *not*.

Comment: @Clare What would be a hypothetical example of such a statement?

Comment: The one on the ACT!  (The comma before *but* is not as necessary, but commas are often placed there.) In other words, the punctuation of the sentence works very well as written in the test.

Comment: When you say _interior punctuation_, are you referring to the dash between _everyday_ and _not_, the comma before _but_, or the single quotes around _Luigi_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence quoted has four sets of punctuation:  The dash after *everyday*, the comma before *but*, the single-quotes around *Luigi*, and the period at the end of it all.

The period is necessary to end the sentence.  I assume you're not asking about that.

I'm not sure why the single quotes are there other than, perhaps, to highlight that the word *Luigi* is a nickname or refers to something one wouldn't normally name (such as a car or motorcycle.)

The dash is there to separate the two parts and the show that the second adds information to the first.

Lastly, and I think this is what you're actually asking about, the comma before *but* is there to indicate the natural pause that many speakers make in that situation.  It is, as @Clare noted, optional.

Comment: Just FYI, the @ symbol doesn't ping people when used in an answer.